# Pygame Text Doesn't Display

Tags: python, pygame, text-rendering

```
def score():
    global x_score, o_score
    
    scoreFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans', 20, bold=True)
    SCORE = scoreFont.render(f'X   {x_score} : {o_score}   O', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(SCORE, ((WIDTH / 2) - (SCORE.get_width() / 2), HEIGHT + SCORE.get_height()))
```

- *WIDTH and HEIGHT = screens width and height*
- *x and o scores are defined*
- *pygame and font are initialized from the start*
- *Called `pygame.display.flip()` after the function*

I have everything else in my code displaying BUT this. Can anyone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong on trying to display the scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score is at the bottom outside the window. Change the calculation of the y-coordinate. The vertical position is `HEIGHT - SCORE.get_height()` instead of `HEIGHT + SCORE.get_height()`:

<s>`screen.blit(SCORE, ((WIDTH / 2) - (SCORE.get_width() / 2), HEIGHT + SCORE.get_height()))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(SCORE, ((WIDTH / 2) - (SCORE.get_width() / 2), HEIGHT - SCORE.get_height()))
```